# How to interpret coefficients of logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm

I'm trying to figure out how the coefficients of logistic regression with a polynomial term relate to predictions. Specifically, I'm interested in the location on the x-axis where the prediction is highest. Example below:

```r
set.seed(42)

# Setup some dummy data
x <- 1:200
y <- rep(0, length(x))
y[51:150] <- rbinom(100, 1, 0.5)

# Fit a model
family <- binomial()
model  <- glm(y ~ poly(x, 2), family = family)

# Illustrate model
plot(x, y)
lines(x, family$linkinv(predict(model)), col = 2)
```

[image]

The model above gives me these coefficients:

```r
coef(model)
#> (Intercept) poly(x, 2)1 poly(x, 2)2 
#>   -1.990317   -3.867855  -33.299893
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

The manual page for `poly()` states the following:

> The orthogonal polynomial is summarized by the coefficients, which can be used to evaluate it via the three-term recursion given in Kennedy & Gentle (1980, pp. 343–4), and used in the predict part of the code.

However, I don't have access to the book, nor am I able to discern from the `predict.glm` S3 method how these coefficients are handled. Is there a way to reconstruct the location of the summit (around 100 in the example) from the coefficients alone (i.e. without using `predict()` to find the maximum)?

Comment: I definetly finds this question enligthening. But how has this not migrated to Stackexchange? Im just curious

Comment: I'm not sure. Can I ask why you think this question might be a better fit for another site?

Comment: Well - the title and the first part is related to logistic regressions per se, but the last part with "Is there a way to reconstruct the location of the summit (around 100 in the example) from the coefficients alone (i.e. without using predict() to find the maximum)" is coding related - So I guess its a grey area, where people way more experienced than me judges whether its suitable for SO or not. Which it obviously is.

Comment: I was genuinely just curious - this wasn't a passive aggressive comment in any way!

Comment: Oh I apologise if I caused confusion, I didn't intend to come across as annoyed or anything! The reason I posted it here is because many R users have a background in data analysis or statistics and thus might be able to help me with the logistic regression bit. I was looking for a solution in R because I'm not eager to go to e.g. matlab or python to solve a problem that I know should be solvable in R where the rest of my project lives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Derivation of the location of the predicted maximum from the theoretical expressions of the orthogonal polynomials

I got a copy of the **"Statistical Computing" book by Kennedy and Gentle (1982)** referenced in the documentation of `poly` and now share my findings about the calculation of the orthogonal polynomials, and how we can use them to find the location x of the maximum predicted value.

The orthogonal polynomials presented in the book (pp. 343-4) are monic (i.e. the highest order coefficient is always 1) and are obtained by the following recurrence procedure:
[image: recurrence relation]

where *q* is the number of orthogonal polynomials considered.

Note the following **relationship of the above terminology** with the documentation of `poly`:

1. The **"three-term recursion"** appearing in the excerpt included in your question is the RHS of the third expression which has precisely three terms.
2. The *rho(j+1)* coefficients in the third expression are called **"centering constants"**.
3. The *gamma(j)* coefficients in the third expression do not have a name in the documentation but they are directly related to the **"normalization constants"**, as seen below.

For reference, here I paste the relevant excerpt of the "Value" section of the `poly` documentation:

> A matrix with rows corresponding to points in x and columns corresponding to the degree, with attributes "degree" specifying the degrees of the columns and (unless raw = TRUE) "coefs" which contains the centering and normalization constants used in constructing the orthogonal polynomials

**Going back to the recurrence**, we can derive the values of parameters *rho(j+1)* and *gamma(j)* from the third expression by imposing the orthogonality condition on *p(j+1)* w.r.t. *p(j)* and *p(j-1)*.
(It's important to note that the orthogonality condition is *not* an integral, but a summation on the *n* observed *x* points, so the polynomial coefficients depend on the data! --which is not the case for instance for the Tchebyshev orthogonal polynomials).

The expressions for the parameters become:
[image: parameters]

For the polynomials of orders 1 and 2 used in your regression, we get the following expressions, already written in R code:

```
# First we define the number of observations in the data
n = length(x)

# For p1(x):
# p1(x) = (x - rho1) p0(x)      (since p_{-1}(x) = 0)
rho1 = mean(x)

# For p2(x)
# p2(x) = (x - rho2) p1(x) - gamma1
gamma1 = var(x) * (n-1)/n
rho2 = sum( x * (x - mean(x))^2 ) / (n*gamma1)
```

for which we get:

```
> c(rho1, rho2, gamma1)
[1]  100.50  100.50 3333.25
```

Note that `coefs` attribute of `poly(x,2)` is:

```
> attr(poly(x,2), "coefs")
$alpha
[1] 100.5 100.5

$norm2
[1]          1        200     666650 1777555560
```

where `$alpha` contains the **centering constants**, i.e. the *rho* values (which coincide with ours --incidentally all centering constants are equal to the average of x when the *distribution of x is symmetric* for any *q*! (observed and proved)), and `$norm2` contains the **normalization constants** (in this case for *p(-1,x)*, *p(0,x)*, *p(1,x)*, and *p(2,x)*), that is the constants *c(j)* that normalize the polynomials in the recurrence formula --by dividing them by *sqrt(c(j))*--, making the resulting polynomials *r(j,x)* satisfy *sum_over_i{ r(j,x_i)^2 } = 1*; **note that *r(j,x)* are the polynomials stored in the object returned by `poly()`**.

From the expression already given above, we observe that *gamma(j)* is precisely the ratio of two consecutive normalization constants, namely: *gamma(j) = c(j) / c(j-1)*.

We can check that our `gamma1` value coincides with this ratio by computing:

```
gamma1 == attr(poly(x,2), "coefs")$norm2[3] / attr(poly(x,2), "coefs")$norm2[2]
```

which returns `TRUE`.

**Going back to your problem of finding the maximum** of the values predicted by your model, we can:

1. Express the predicted value as a function of r(1,x) and r(2,x) and the coefficients from the logistic regression, namely:

   *pred(x) = beta0 + beta1 * r(1,x) + beta2 * r(2,x)*
2. Derive the expression w.r.t. x, set it to 0 and solve for x.

In R code:

```
# Get the normalization constants alpha(j) to obtain r(j,x) from p(j,x) as
# r(j,x) = p(j,x) / sqrt( norm(j) ) = p(j,x) / alpha(j)
alpha1 = sqrt( attr(poly(x,2), "coefs")$norm2[3] )
alpha2 = sqrt( attr(poly(x,2), "coefs")$norm2[4] )

# Get the logistic regression coefficients (beta1 and beta2)
coef1 = as.numeric( model$coeff["poly(x, 2)1"] )
coef2 = as.numeric( model$coeff["poly(x, 2)2"] )

# Compute the x at which the maximum occurs from the expression that is obtained
# by deriving the predicted expression pred(x) = beta0 + beta1*r(1,x) + beta2*r(2,x)
# w.r.t. x and setting the derivative to 0.
xmax = ( alpha2^-1 * coef2 * (rho1 + rho2) - alpha1^-1 * coef1 ) / (2 * alpha2^-1 * coef2)
```

which gives:

```
> xmax
[1] 97.501114
```

i.e. **the same value obtained with the other "empirical" method** described in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68653562/6118609).

---

The **full code** to obtain the location x of the maximum of the predicted values, starting off from the code you provided, is:

```
# First we define the number of observations in the data
n = length(x)

# Parameters for p1(x):
# p1(x) = (x - rho1) p0(x)      (since p_{-1}(x) = 0)
rho1 = mean(x)

# Parameters for p2(x)
# p2(x) = (x - rho2) p1(x) - gamma1
gamma1 = var(x) * (n-1)/n
rho2 = mean( x * (x - mean(x))^2 ) / gamma1

# Get the normalization constants alpha(j) to obtain r(j,x) from p(j,x) as
# r(j,x) = p(j,x) / sqrt( norm(j) ) = p(j,x) / alpha(j)
alpha1 = sqrt( attr(poly(x,2), "coefs")$norm2[3] )
alpha2 = sqrt( attr(poly(x,2), "coefs")$norm2[4] )

# Get the logistic regression coefficients (beta1 and beta2)
coef1 = as.numeric( model$coeff["poly(x, 2)1"] )
coef2 = as.numeric( model$coeff["poly(x, 2)2"] )

# Compute the x at which the maximum occurs from the expression that is obtained
# by deriving the predicted expression pred(x) = beta0 + beta1*r(1,x) + beta2*r(2,x)
# w.r.t. x and setting the derivative to 0.
( xmax = ( alpha2^-1 * coef2 * (rho1 + rho2) - alpha1^-1 * coef1 ) / (2 * alpha2^-1 * coef2) )
```

Comment: Great stuff, thanks for going through the effort of looking for the book and figuring out how this relates to my question! I've put out a bounty for your answer, but I have to wait a day to award the bounty.

Comment: Great, I am glad you found the answer useful, and thank you for your feedback and for requesting the bounty! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to find the maximum of the prediction *analytically* for this particular case where the orthogonal polynomials are of order 1 and 2, I propose the following approach:

#### SUMMARY

##### 1) Infer the polynomial coefficients

This can easily be done by fitting a linear model to the respective polynomial values contained in the model matrix.

##### 2) Derive the prediction expression w.r.t. x and set the derivative to 0

Solve for `x` in the prediction expression inferred from the polynomial fit in (1) and obtain the value of `x` at which the prediction's maximum occurs.

#### DETAILS

##### 1) Polynomial coefficients

Following from the line where you fit the GLM model, we estimate the coefficients for the polynomial of order 1, `p1(x) = a0 + a1*x`, and the coefficients for the polynomial of order 2, `p2(x) = b0 + b1*x + b2*x^2`:

```
X = model.matrix(model)
p1 = X[, "poly(x, 2)1"]
p2 = X[, "poly(x, 2)2"]

p1.lm = lm(p1 ~ x)
a0 = p1.lm$coeff["(Intercept)"]
a1 = p1.lm$coeff["x"]

p2.lm = lm(p2 ~ x + I(x^2))
b0 = p2.lm$coeff["(Intercept)"]
b1 = p2.lm$coeff["x"]
b2 = p2.lm$coeff["I(x^2)"]
```

This gives:

```
> c(a0, a1, b0, b1, b2)
   (Intercept)              x    (Intercept)              x         I(x^2) 
-1.2308840e-01  1.2247602e-03  1.6050353e-01 -4.7674315e-03  2.3718565e-05
```

##### 2) Derivative of the prediction to find the maximum

The expression for the prediction, `z`, (before the inverse link function) is:

`z = Intercept + coef1 * p1(x) + coef2 * p2(x)`

We derive this expression and set it to 0 to obtain:

`coef1 * a1 + coef2 * (b1 + 2 * b2 * xmax) = 0`

Solving for `xmax` we get:

`xmax = - (coef1 * a1 + coef2 * b1) / (2 * coef2 * b2)`

In R code, this is computed as:

```
coef1 = as.numeric( model$coeff["poly(x, 2)1"] )
coef2 = as.numeric( model$coeff["poly(x, 2)2"] )
(xmax = - ( coef1 * a1 + coef2 * b1 ) / (2 * coef2 * b2))
```

which gives:

```
        x 
97.501114
```

#### CHECK

We can verify the maximum by adding it to the prediction's curve as a green cross:

```
# Prediction curve computed analytically
Intercept = model$coeff["(Intercept)"]
pred.analytical = family$linkinv( Intercept + coef1 * p1 + coef2 * p2 )

# Find the prediction's maximum analytically
pred.max = family$linkinv( Intercept + coef1 * (a0 + a1 * xmax) +
                                       coef2 * (b0 + b1 * xmax + b2 * xmax^2) )


# Plot
plot(x, y)
# The following two lines should coincide!
lines(x, pred.analytical, col = 3)
lines(x, family$linkinv(predict(model)), col = 2)
# Location of the maximum!
points(xmax, pred.max, pch="x", col="green")
```

which gives:

[image]